# Remove numerics in column prior to value_counts

Tags: python, pandas, count

I have a string df. I want to find a quick summary of the string columns, and am using describe as below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['1','2','C','T','A','00400'],
              'col2':['3241','H2','C8','T4','123','0000']})
df['col1'].value_counts()
pd.to_numeric(df['col1'], errors='coerce').describe()
```

but I also want to get a value count of the non numerics. How can I do that?

In this case, `df['Col1'].value_counts(non_numerics)` would yeild:

```
A  1
C  1
T  1
```

As my data has 1m rows, I would like to remove the numerics prior to completing the value counts.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the non-numeric:

```
m = pd.to_numeric(df['col1'], errors='coerce').isna()

out = df.loc[m, 'col1'].value_counts()
```

Output:

```
col1
C    1
T    1
A    1
Name: count, dtype: int64
```

If you have initially NaNs in the column and want to count them as well:

```
m1 = df['col1'].isna()
m2 = pd.to_numeric(df['col1'], errors='coerce').isna()

out = df.loc[m1|m2, 'col1'].value_counts(dropna=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

One-line approach using [`Series.str.isnumeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.isnumeric.html) (negated with `~`):

```
df['col1'][~df['col1'].str.isnumeric()].value_counts()
```

---

```
col1
C    1
T    1
A    1
Name: count, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Just a note to highlight the difference between our answers if this is of importance. Mine would remove decimal numbers (e.g., `'1.2'`), yours would keep them.

Comment: unfortunately, got the error: `TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'`, despite having unique columnar values `D, U, I, 1, 2, 4, 6`, and lots of `NaN`

Comment: @frank, if you `col1` contains different type values use this:  `df['col1'][~df['col1'].astype(str).str.isnumeric()].value_counts()`

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
df.loc[~df['col1'].str.contains('\d'), 'col1'].value_counts()
```

Output:

```
col1
C    1
T    1
A    1
Name: count, dtype: int64
```

Comment: If you use this on col2 this would remove all values (again, depends on what is needed exactly) ;)

Comment: True, @mozway! In such a case, the OP may use `df.loc[df['col2'].str.contains('\D'), 'col2'].value_counts()` instead. Thanks! :-)

Comment: unfortunately, received this error: `ValueError: Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values`

Comment: It works perfectly on my side, @frank. Therefore, I suspect that the example posted in your question does not entirely reproduce the actual dataset you are work on.